# Get value from db from 2 table and short value on base off one variable

Tags: php

We have two table

```
stu_Map

sn  roll  
1     1   
2     2    
3     2    
4     4    
5     3    

student

sn username roll marks

1    Raj     1     23

2    Maik    2     43

3    tini    3     43 

4    tinka   4    24

5    raju    5     20
```

select roll from stu_map and get value from student and after this short on base on Marks.

Comment: You need to clarify this better.

Comment: What is your question? Are you wanting a SQL or PHP solution? May we see some code from you, to show you have done some independent research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to `join` a table and then `order by` a column.

```
SELECT s.sn, s.username, s.roll, s.marks, m.roll FROM Studen s
    JOIN sn_Map m on s.sn = m.sn
ORDER BY s.marks
```

The current `ORDER BY` is Acceding you can make this Descending like

```
 ORDER BY s.marks DESC
```

Comment: we need only roll number 2. which in stu_map.

Comment: Thanks For Help ... its done